# MySQL Joins and Queries

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to write a query that pulls information from two or three tables.

It's structured in such a way that the tables have a `clientid` in common.  I would like to translate that `clientid` to a `client name`, which is stored in another column.

One table lists my clients (`clients`), it has a column named `clientid` and `name` (which says Client A, client B, etc)

One table lists maintenance windows (`maintenancewindow`), it have columns called `maintenanceid` as well as `name` (which says Sunday, Monday, etc)

One table lists my clients locations (`locations`), it also have columns called `maintenanceid` as well as `clientid`.

The end goal is to get a list of my clients name, location, and maintenance windows in readable format, That is the names of clients, locations, maintenance windows versus the 'id's'.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Marc

Comment: I think you need a good tutorial about the very basics of SQL. Any decent tutorial will cover these extensively. When you get actual SQL code that doesn't work, come back here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,clientid FROM clients a 
JOIN maintenancewindow b ON a.clientid=b.clientid 
JOIN locations c ON b.maintenanceid=c.maintenanceid
```

I`m assuming that is the result you want

> The end goal is to get a list of my clients name, location, and
>   maintenance windows in readable format, ie the names of clients,
>   locations, maintenance windows versus the 'id's'.

This part is confusing.You mean a specific id?Just add `WHERE id=someid`.